# For any prime $p ≠ 2,5$, prove there are at most four values of the last digit of any power $p^{i}$?

Tags: functions, induction

I am currently working on this question and I am thoroughly stuck. I believe that this question is saying that for any prime $p$, there will be four or less numerals $p-1$ that exist in the numeral $p$. Inductively we could show this is true for $n ≥ 2$ but I'm not sure if I am on the right track or not.

Comment: No, it’s asking you to show that if you were to write down the sequence of numbers $p^i$ for $i\ge 1$, only (at most) four different one’s digits (rightmost digits) would appear. For instance, with $p=7$ you get $\color{red}7$, $4\color{red}9$, $34\color{red}3$, $240\color{red}1$, and then the last digits $7,9,3,1$ repeat. (In fact the theorem is true for $p=2$ and $p=5$ as well.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** If $gcd(p,10)=1$ then, as $\phi(10)=4$ we have
$$p^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$

Use this to show that the powers of $p$ $\pmod{10}$ repeat after 4 steps.

Answer (score 2):

(Hint for someone who doesn't know what $\phi$ means)

When you rule out even numbers and multiples of $5$, what could the ones digit be?